# Can we put hash tables inside a hash table?

Tags: java, hashtable, spreadsheet

Can we link another hash table for each key, in a hash table?

My target is to have a very fast 2-d data structure to store cells in a spreadsheet.

I'll store "all columns within a row" in a hash table. Then do this to all 'r' number of rows. Next make the final hash table for rows and store all the 'r' number of hash tables in the new hash table. is this way efficient? or is there a better way?

Comment: Have you actually tried it? :) Then you wouldn't have to ask it. Yes, of course you can do it.

Comment: You mean something like `HashTable<String, HashTable<String, String>>`? Yeah why not.

Comment: I tried, it worked but I'm not sure it's the efficient way to do that because of memory wastage.. I just need you guy's advises.

Comment: You can put *anything which is an Object* into a *hash table*. A Hash Table is an object as well :P.

Comment: @malit.tilak how much memory do you have and how much do you need to load? i.e. is a small amount of wastage a problem? If you want a 2D map why not have `Map<Pair<Integer, Integer>, ValueType>`

Comment: thanks for your quick answers. I just found a simpler solution..
I only need a single array of hash tables. I can get array indexes as row numbers and "keys of each hash table" as "column numbers of each row".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
Map<String, Map<Integer,Integer>> asdf = new HashMap<String, Map<Integer, Integer>>();
```

But to be honest you should start with wrapping it inside an object. In this structure globally will be very inconvenient.

You could try this BiHashMap

```
public class BiHashMap<K1, K2, V> {

private final Map<K1, Map<K2, V>> mMap;

public BiHashMap() {
    mMap = new HashMap<K1, Map<K2, V>>();
}

/**
 * Associates the specified value with the specified keys in this map (optional operation). If the map previously
 * contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.
 * 
 * @param key1
 *            the first key
 * @param key2
 *            the second key
 * @param value
 *            the value to be set
 * @return the value previously associated with (key1,key2), or <code>null</code> if none
 * @see Map#put(Object, Object)
 */
public V put(K1 key1, K2 key2, V value) {
    Map<K2, V> map;
    if (mMap.containsKey(key1)) {
        map = mMap.get(key1);
    } else {
        map = new HashMap<K2, V>();
        mMap.put(key1, map);
    }

    return map.put(key2, value);
}

/**
 * Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or <code>null</code> if this map contains no mapping for
 * the key.
 * 
 * @param key1
 *            the first key whose associated value is to be returned
 * @param key2
 *            the second key whose associated value is to be returned
 * @return the value to which the specified key is mapped, or <code>null</code> if this map contains no mapping for
 *         the key
 * @see Map#get(Object)
 */
public V get(K1 key1, K2 key2) {
    if (mMap.containsKey(key1)) {
        return mMap.get(key1).get(key2);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns <code>true</code> if this map contains a mapping for the specified key
 * 
 * @param key1
 *            the first key whose presence in this map is to be tested
 * @param key2
 *            the second key whose presence in this map is to be tested
 * @return Returns true if this map contains a mapping for the specified key
 * @see Map#containsKey(Object)
 */
public boolean containsKeys(K1 key1, K2 key2) {
    return mMap.containsKey(key1) && mMap.get(key1).containsKey(key2);
}

public void clear() {
    mMap.clear();
}

}
```

And then create use it like this:

```
BiHashMap<String,String,String> bigBoard = new BiHashMap<String,String,String>();
```